# how to add dragend event on svg element

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, d3.js

I am using D3.js to drag SVG elements, using concept of [D3.js drag](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-on). drag is working fine but I want to call a function on dragend. How to do that?

Here is [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sb2BX/20/). I simply want to call a function on dragend.

Should I try

```
var drop = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("dragend", function () { alert(); });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seemed to be trying to do some kind of nested dragging or something, the following should work:

```
 var drag1 = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove)
    .on("dragend", function () { alert("drag ended"); });
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/xnjGD/

Comment: This has changed to just `end` instead of `dragend` in D3 v4. [Example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/204d08d309d2b2903e12554b0aef6a4d)

Answer (score 0):

Quick mention if anyone still needs something like this, `d3.behaviour` was deprecated as well as `dragend`. If you still need the functionality it should look something like this:

```
d3.drag().on("end", (_event, dimension) => {
    console.log("alert ended for : " dimension)
  })
```

(for more informations: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#dragging-d3-drag)